# Erro:Unable to determine type from: <. Last 1 characters read: <

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver

#### Please note that this issue tracker is not a help form and this issue will be closed.

For questions or help please see:

- [SeleniumHQ IRC channel](https://webchat.freenode.net/)
- [SeleniumHQ Slack channel](https://seleniumhq.herokuapp.com/)
- The [Selenium Users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users) google group

#### 1. the error code

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/displayhelpservlet.css" media="all"/>
  <link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/displayhelpservlet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var json = Object.freeze('{"consoleLink": "\u002fwd\u002fhub","type": "Standalone","class": "org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DisplayHelpHandler$DisplayHelpServletConfig","version": "3.141.59"}');
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
  <div id="help-heading">
    <h1><span id="logo"></span></h1>
    <h2>Selenium <span class="se-type"></span>&nbsp;v.<span class="se-version"></span></h2>
  </div>

  <div id="content-body">
    <p>
      Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.
    </p>
    <p>
      For more information about Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> please see the
      <a class="se-docs">docs</a> and/or visit the <a class="se-wiki">wiki</a>.
      <span id="console-item">
        Or perhaps you are looking for the Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> <a class="se-console">console</a>.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Happy Testing!
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <footer id="help-footer">
      Selenium is made possible through the efforts of our open source community, contributions from
      these <a href="https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/AUTHORS">people</a>, and our
      <a href="http://www.seleniumhq.org/sponsors/">sponsors</a>.
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.zhangmeng.zhi_hui_tree.ZhiHuiTreeApplication.main(ZhiHuiTreeApplication.java:21)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine type from: <. Last 1 characters read: <
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'zhangmengdeMacBook-Pro.local', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.2', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.peek(JsonInput.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.lambda$null$6(JsonTypeCoercer.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.coerce(JsonTypeCoercer.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:112)
    ... 7 more
```

#### 2. What did I do

in this [docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium),I pull *selenium/standalone-chrome*

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size=2g --name selenium selenium/standalone-chrome
```

my code

```java
SpringApplication.run(ZhiHuiTreeApplication.class, args);
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("headless", "no-sandbox", "window-size=1200x800");
        WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4445"), chromeOptions);
        webDriver.get("https://www.baidu.com/");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tsf\"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]"));
        System.out.println(element.getText());
        webDriver.quit();
```

Maven info

```java
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
```

#### 3. I am newbie, not particularly understanding, thank you for your help

Comment: Did you found the fix ? Having the same issue here

Answer (score 0):

only add **"/wd/hub"** in your URL
example:

```
 WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4445/wd/hub"), chromeOptions);
```

bye